# How to plot a simple circle in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles, plot, circles

I want to plot one simple circle, but this code is giving me the most grief. Here is what I have written:

```
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    yticklabels={,,}
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{x^2 +y^2 =1};



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Predicted graph for for position versus time.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

But every time I try to compile, it throws an exception. I also tried just plotting half of the circle using

```
\addplot [
        domain=-10:10, 
        samples=100, 
        color=red,
    ]
    {\sqrt{1-x^2}};
```

but to no avail. Nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. How do you plot a circle (and, for that matter, half a circle) using pgfplots?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

Is there a reason for not simply using `circle` and `arc` of TikZ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, ticks=none}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xmin=-11, xmax=11, ymin=-11, ymax=11,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = {$f(x)$},
        yticklabels={,,}
        ]
        \draw (axis cs: 0, 0) circle [radius=10];% I've set the radius to 10 only for better show the image
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xmin=-11, xmax=11, ymin=-11, ymax=11,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = {$f(x)$},
        yticklabels={,,}
        ]
        \draw (axis cs: 10,0) arc[radius =10, start angle= 0, end angle= 180];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I just saw the question and was thinking of exactly the same ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow maybe there is a reason, but sometimes people complicate their lives uselessly... :)

Comment: The actual question is how do you draw circles when `axis` are not `equal`

Comment: @percusse Hahaha, there are various schools of thought on what the OP wanted to ask, let's wait his explanation! :)

Answer (score 7):

You could use polar coordinates and simply plot sin(x).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      domain     = 0:180,
      samples    = 100,
      axis lines = none,
    ]
    \addplot[thick] {sin(x)};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: circle]

I used it here extended in 2d and 3d: [Periodic, more or less](http://tikz.de/periodisch/) (German) following a question on [TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7828/wie-kann-man-einen-zweidimensionalen-polaren-plot-mit-pgfplots-in-die-dritte-dimension-heben).

Comment: Is there any particular reason for plotting sin(x) instead of 1?

Comment: @Emma No, just that sin(x) is way more cool than 1. ;-)  Well, sin and cos with factors and addition gives nice graphs. A simple sin or cos looks like a circle as 1 does, just with a different position in relation to the origin.

Answer (score 6):

Your first attempt throws errors because it doesn't know how to plot an implicit function (in particular, it is confused by the syntax `=`). The second is correct except that you should use `sqrt` instead of `\sqrt`. The slightly modified command

```
\addplot[domain=-1:1, samples=100, color=red] {sqrt(1-x^2)};
```

should work to plot half a circle. (Note that the correct domain is important to get the ends of the half circle.)

For the whole circle, instead of giving an implicit function you can use a parameterization:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines = left,
      xlabel = $x$,
      ylabel = {$f(x)$},
      yticklabels={,,}
  ]
  \addplot [domain=-180:180, samples=100, color=red] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I hope it is clear how to modify this to give a half circle.)

Comment: Your circle is not a perfect circle, measure (horizontally and vertically) the radius with a ruler. I think it is due to the different scale of the axes.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, that is for sure the reason, because by default the `width` and the `height` of the `axis` environment aren't equal (besides that `scale only axis` is `false` by default. If the circle should also "visibly" be a circle, Emma just needs to add `axis equal` to the `axis` options.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, hopefully you already know that, because you used `axis equal` yourself in your answer;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yes, but I've discovered it today, while I was testing my solution! Every day you learn something new (also answering) on TEX.SE!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, the same is true for me.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I was assuming that by "plot a circle" the OP meant "plot the graph of the circle given by x^2 + y^2 = 1" rather than "draw a picture of a circle." Now that I look, it's not obvious from the question which one is intended.

Comment: Yes, Emma, the question is not completely clear, that's why I asked if there is a reason for not using TikZ options. Let's wait for the OP's clarification!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution to "just draw a circle" is for sure the solution provided by [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338908/95441).

Here I just present a similar solution to the one of [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338873/95441) by just using polar coordinates in a normal `axis` environment instead of a `polar` one.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            data cs=polar,
            smooth,
%            % if you want the (half) circles to look like
%            % circles instead of ellipses ...
%            axis equal,
        ]
            \addplot+ [domain=0:360]   {2};
            \addplot+ [domain=180:360] {1.25};

            % just for fun
            % (please note that *only* PGFPlots stuff now uses polar coordinates.
            %  The TikZ stuff still uses cartesian coordinates)
            \fill [red] (axis cs:0.5,0.75) circle (5pt);
            \fill [red] (axis cs:-0.5,0.75) circle (5pt);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: @CarLaTeX, nope, I left it with intent *commented*. As one can see, the circles *are* circles with respect to the axis ticks. I also thought of scaling one of the axis to make it clear that the result does not provide a circle not taking the axis into account ...

Comment: I've only watched at the picture without looking at the code, sorry :$

Answer (score 0):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{picture}(100,100)(0,0)
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\put(20,70){\circle{30}}  \put(20,70){\circle*{10}}   % left eye
\put(80,70){\circle{30}}  \put(80,70){\circle*{10}}   % right eye
\put(40,40){\line(1,2){10}} \put(60,40){\line(-1,2){10}} \put(40,40){\line(1,0){20}} % nose
\put(50,20){\oval(80,10)[b]} % mouth
\multiput(0,90)(4,0){10}{\line(1,3){4}}  % left eyebrow
\multiput(100,90)(-4,0){10}{\line(-1,3){4}}  % right eyebrow
\end{picture}
\end{center}
```

check here there are more better examples, more minimalist for education purposes:
https://github.com/spartrekus/Latex-tfig-resource-figure